# Strange behavior in serialization of Date objects

Tags: java, serialization

I have some problem with date object, it seems that date object is updated at the instant of its serialization, and not at the instant of its creation, using the method **Date()**. I'm almost sure about of this behavior, because my code don't change the value of the date object.

Am i thinking right?

Comment: `Date` can be converted to a `long` value. No need to serialize it.

Comment: Write a SSCCE which reproduces the problem you're talking about. My guess is that you'll find, while writing it, that your assumption is wrong and that the strange behavior you observe come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am i thinking right?

No you are not.  If you read the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html) for the `java.util.Date` class, you will see that your theory is not correct.  The only thing that it does that *might* be unexpected is that serializing causes the `Date` object to be normalized before the "milliseconds since 1970" time is serialized.

Your assumptions about your program's behaviour are probably incorrect.  At any rate, *something else* is going on here ...